# Keith Clark nor Scrollmagic working for Parallax Background -- CSS preferred but jQuery tips are helpful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on displaying about 30 images in a flexbox list with a larger image in the background. I want to use this format over and over so making it compatible with different sizes is a must. The flexbox list isn't the problem, the parallax background is. So far I have tried out Keith Clark's parallax idea to no avail. I have also tried out ScrollMagic with GSAP and it is just very choppy and looks poor upon scrolling.

Right now my content is structured like this:

```
<div id="xScrollHolder">
<div id="bgImageWrapper">
 <img id="bgImage" src="parallaxbackgroundImage">
</div>
<div id="xScrollContent">
  <div id="flexboxContent">
  </div>
  <div id="flexboxContent">
  </div>
  <div id="flexboxContent">
  </div>
  <div id="flexboxContent">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The containing element, xScrollHolder, is currently sized at 100vw and 100vh but the content holder, xScrollContent, is at auto to fit as much flexboxContent as possible.

Again, I'm looking to display just that one image as the background throughout. I may be doing something wrong with Keith Clark's tutorial but for some reason I can't get the image to fill the background without it turning to shite.

Thanks.